# Kafka streams aggregate with deletes and/or key changes

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to define a kafka stream which accepts records from a topic, say, EMPLOYEE, where the records contain attributes about an employee and its department,  and transform it into another topic, DEPARTMENT, which contains department attributes, and a list of all the employees (with a few stateless transformations on the employee thrown in).

The EMPLOYEE records repeat the department data.  (*I'm actually dealing with some DICOM header data, but I'll stick with a more universally understood relationship. I'm trying to understand a general solution*).   Also, the records in the topic only have the current data (i.e.: no prior departmentId, if the department changed.)

This seems like a job for aggregate.  I have something that seems to work for the simple case:

```
        ...
        KStream<String, Employee> stream = kStreamBuilder.stream("EMPLOYEE"); // Stream from raw EMPLOYEE
        stream.map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(k, transformEmployee(v))) // <-- some stateless enrichment of the employee
                .groupBy((k, emp) -> emp.getDepartmentId(), jsonSerialisedWith(Employee.class))

                // dummy reduce to a get a ktable for agg:
                .reduce((aggValue, newEmp) -> newEmp) 
                .groupBy((k, emp2) -> new KeyValue<>(emp2.getDepartmentId(), emp2), jsonSerialisedWith(Employee.class))

                .aggregate(Department::new, this::addEmployee, this::removeEmployee,
                           jsonValueMaterializedAs("DEPARTMENT-AGG", Department.class))
                .toStream()
                .to("DEPARTMENT", jsonProducedWith(Department.class));
        ...

    private Department addEmployee(String deptId, Employee employee, Department department) {
        department.addEmployee(employee);
        if (department.getId() == null) {
            department.setId(employee.getDepartmentId());
            department.setName(employee.getDepartmentName());
        }
        return department;
    }
```

This works for the add or update. However over time, an employee may be deleted or reassigned to another department.  I gather the delete should be a tombstone record (k:empId, v: null) sent to the EMPLOYEE topic.  However, I no longer have the departmentId, I'd have to do a null check (and return null for the departmentId), so removeEmployee never occurs when an employee is deleted. 
 Similar issue for a change of departmentId.

So, what's the kafka way to approach this?

Comment: You requirement are complex and thus not easily expressible using the DSL. I would recommend to use the Processor API instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is enough to use your code, but slightly change the semantic of deleting the employee.

You should add some kind of `Mock` department (will be used, when user is removed from department).

If employee is removed, instead setting department to `null`, it should be assigned to `Mock` department.

Answer (score 0):

We should first change key of employee stream then join with department stream with value joiner and then groupByKey to aggregate

```
 KStream<String, Employee> stream = kStreamBuilder.stream("EMPLOYEE"); // Stream from raw EMPLOYEE
        stream.selectKey((k,v) -> v.getDeptId())
              .join(deptStream, <joiner function >)
              .groupByKey()
              .aggregrate(//init,add,//).toStream();
```